# Как представить матрицу инцидентности в алгебраической форме?

Tags: python, матрицы

К примеру, имеется граф в алгебраической форме: `(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)`. Я написал небольшой код для нахождения матрицы инцидентности для этого графа. Теперь мне бы хотелось сделать все наоборот. Из матрицы инцидентности представить граф в алгебраической форме. Как бы это реализовать?

Вот мой код, который показывает матрицу инцидентности:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    count_reber = int(input('Введите кол-во ребер: '))
    count_vershin = int(input('Введите кол-во вершин: '))

    list_reber = []

    for i in range(count_reber):
        rebro = str(input(f'Введите ребро {i+1}, пример 0,0: ')).split(',')
        list_reber.append([int(rebro[0]),int(rebro[1])])

    for i in range(count_reber):
        print(f'({list_reber[i][0]},{list_reber[i][1]})')

    matrix = [[0] * count_vershin for i in range(count_reber)]

    for i in range(count_reber):
        for j in range(count_vershin):
            # print(type(list_reber[i][0]),type(list_reber[i][1]),type(j))
            if list_reber[i][0] == j+1 or list_reber[i][1] == j+1:
                matrix[i][j] = 1
            else:
                matrix[i][j] = 0

    print(matrix)
    for i in range(count_reber):
        for j in range(count_vershin):
            print(matrix[i][j], end=' ')
        print()
```

Ввожу так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пройтись по столбцам. Номера строк, в которых в этом столбце будут единицы (вообще, там могут быть еще и -1) - это номера вершин инцидентных ребру соответствующему этому столбцу.

Comment: Спасибо! Отличная идея

Comment: @extrn Хотел бы спросить про другое. Как представить граф из матрицы инцидентности в виде реберного графа? То есть ребра становятся вершинами, а вершины ребрами. Сможете подсказать алгоритм?

Comment: Теперь нужно идти по рядам, брать комбинации по два элемента для всех единичных элементов ряда. Каждая такая пара будет ребром нового графа, Например `[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]`. Из первого ряда `(e1, e2), (e1, e3), (e2, e3)`, из второго `(e1, e4)`, из третьего `(e2, e4)`, в четвертом только одна единица, значит ребер нет.

Comment: @extrn что имеется ввиду под "ряд"? строки?

Comment: @extrn цикл нужно делать по столбцам? Или по строкам?

Comment: да, строки. Внешний цикл по строкам, внутренний(внутренние) по столбцам.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для неориентированного графа. В каждом столбце будет только две единицы или одна в случае петли. Добавляем номера строк +1 в список temp - это будет ребро -> добавляем ребра в общий список рёбер

```
matrix = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
algForm = []
for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    temp = []
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        if matrix[j][i] == 1:
            temp.append(j + 1)
    if len(temp) == 1: # проверка на петлю
        temp.append(temp[0])
    algForm.append(tuple(temp))
print(*algForm)
```